# Can you delete a windows task with another task trough powershell?

Tags: powershell, task

When using following powershell script which creates a scheduled task to delete another scheduled task, I am confronted with an error (access denied: 0x80070005). When I manually define the task and execute it, it works fine.

```
# Prep task 2 for taskscheduler > delete task 1 after reboot if not deleted before
$Action2    = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" -Argument "/c schtasks /delete /tn 'Computer Forced Reboot'/f"
$Trigger2   = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogon
$Settings2  = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -Compatibility Win8 -RestartCount:10 -RestartInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1)
$Principal2 = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "domain\$env:UserName" -LogonType Interactive
    
# Register task 2 to Taskscheduler
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "test test" -Action $Action2 -Trigger $Trigger2 -Settings $Settings2 -Principal $Principal2here
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this not possible (specific rights) trough powershell? Is there a workaround?

Comment: A domain user most likely doesn't have local administrator privileges, required to delete a task.

Comment: I'd have it run as the local SYSTEM account, and happen at boot up rather than login.

Comment: thx, no joy however. I took another strategy to accomplish the task.